# Azure resource graph query re-write default tag response

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to alter the default response of Azure Resource graph query into similar that Azure portal uses. My query is:

```
resourcecontainers | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions" | project name, tags
```

From where the response for tags is:

```
  "tags": {
    "TagA": "TeamA",
    "TagB": "TeamB",
    "TagC": "TeamC"
  },
```

I would like to alter this into:

```
    "tags": [
  {
    "name": "TagA",
    "value": "TeamA"
  },
  {
    "name": "TagB",
    "value": "TeamB"
  },
  {
    "name": "TagC",
    "value": "TeamC"
  }
]
```

How to do it? All examples I have found are either for only one tag or static set of tags. Mine would need to support dynamic amount of tags.

Comment: Could you please try with this `cmd`     `resourcecontainers
    | where subscriptionId == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'| mvexpand parsejson(tags)| extend tagname = tostring(bag_keys(tags)[0])| extend tagvalue = tostring(tags[tagname])| project name, tagname, tagvalue` 
This cmd will list with tag name and value . Is this the same you are looking for.

Comment: it is almost what I am looking for. In your solution the subscription name is added into each array item. I can remove it from the projection though and join it to my other query.

Comment: Okay i am posting the same as an answer by removing the subscription id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have confirmed to achieve the above requirement we can do it using the below query

```
resourcecontainers      
| where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
| mvexpand parsejson(tags)
| extend tagname = tostring(bag_keys(tags)[0])
| extend tagvalue = tostring(tags[tagname])
| project name, tagname, tagvalue
```

***Output:-***
[image]

For more information please refer this [***BLOG***](https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/working-with-tags-in-azure-resource-graph-explorer)